# Scroll items in RecyclerView so last item is always the same when soft keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a messaging app, nothing fancy about the layout - a `Toolbar` at the top of the layout, an `EditText` at the bottom and a `RecyclerView` for the list of messages, filling the space in-between.

My issue is that the **position of the last visible item** in the `RecyclerView` is not maintained when the soft keyboard is shown by clicking/pressing the `EditText`. i.e. if the list has 20 items and the last visible when the soft keyboard isn't shown is item 12, when the soft keyboard is shown I'd still like the last visible to be item 12.

I already tried a combination of *adjustPan* and *adjustResize* in the manifest and in code but doesn't solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not really. Most of the solutions I landed on involve a lot of height adjustments and calculations on the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to set `adjustResize` in the manifest then create a custom `RecyclerView` subclass that overrides `onLayout()`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        int height = b - t;
        if (height != mLastHeight) {
            int last = getAdapter.getItemCount() - 1;
            scrollToPosition(last);
        }
        mLastHeight = height;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This essentially scrolls to the last item in the list, which isn't what I'd like done. I've updated the question to give more clarity.